# Is it possible to create a SnowFlake function that performs an update on a table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FIX_DATE ("DATE1" DATE)
RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE SQL
STRICT 
AS  '
    UPDATE table_a
    SET my_date = DATE1;

    SELECT my_date
    FROM table_a
    ';
```

I am expecting field to be updated and return success or failure or the DATE1 value.

Comment: So what happened when you tried it? What’s the actual issue you are facing?

Comment: No. UDFs only project rows. You can't define any command other than SELECT in a SQL UDF, and usually only SQL fragments without the SELECT command. If you want to define a delete statement that is dynamic you can use an anonymous block with SQL Script or a stored procedure using one of the several supported languages for SPs.

Comment: That's what I thought but wasn't sure.  Redesigned to be called in a procedure instead.